# Problem with textbook proof of Lamé's Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am currently reading an introductory number theory textbook and I have a problem with the following proof:

(note that $F_n$ denotes the n-th Fibonacci number)

[image]

In the last step, it seems to apply the logarithm of the golden ratio to both sides of the inequality $b \le g^n$ -- wouldn't this result in $n \le \log_g(b)$ instead of $n < \log_g(b)$?

Comment: Yes, seems like a typo.

Comment: Is that Mollin's book?  It was his style that his proofs and solutions were full of references to other pages and exercises.  Very annoying to keep flipping back and forth.

Comment: Yes, it's Mollin's book.

Comment: My advice is that you get a different book.  You're going to keep running into the same problem otherwise.